# deserialize json with java jackson

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, gson

I am trying to deserialize the following response from an `API`:

```
{
    "claims": [
        {
            "amount": 3953,
            "dateReceived": "2014-8-02",
            "groupCode": "3947",
            "id": 544477,
            "invoiceDate": "2014-8-01",
            "invoiceNumber": "43443433634",
            "memberNames": "FFFEE GTFSS",
            "memberNumber": "FD56DFD6F",
            "providerCode": "241",
            "serviceTags": {
                "diagnosis": "jkfkfgkh",
                "quantity": "6",
                "serviceAmount": "3434",
                "serviceCode": "097090",
                "serviceCodeType": "69696",
                "serviceDescription": "twertret",
                "serviceType": "ghkgk",
                "transactionId": 58
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "claims" , not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: , "memberNumber", "groupCode", "memberNames", "serviceTags", "dateReceived", "invoiceNumber", "amount", "id", "invoiceDate", "providerCode"])Unrecognized field "claims"
```

Here are my classes:

```
public class Claim {

    private int id;

    private String groupCode;
    private String providerCode;
    private String memberNumber;
    private String memberNames;
    private Date invoiceDate;
    private long amount;  
    private Date dateReceived;
    private String invoiceNumber;
    private ServiceTag serviceTags ;


    public Claim() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ServiceTag getServiceTags() {
        return serviceTags;
    }
    public void setServiceTags(ServiceTag serviceTags) {
        this.serviceTags = serviceTags;
    }

    public String getGroupCode() {
        return groupCode;
    }
    public void setGroupCode(String groupCode) {
        this.groupCode = groupCode;
    }
    public String getProviderCode() {
        return providerCode;
    }
    public void setProviderCode(String providerCode) {
        this.providerCode = providerCode;
    }
    public String getMemberNumber() {
        return memberNumber;
    }
    public void setMemberNumber(String memberNumber) {
        this.memberNumber = memberNumber;
    }
    public String getMemberNames() {
        return memberNames;
    }
    public void setMemberNames(String memberNames) {
        this.memberNames = memberNames;
    }

    public Date getInvoiceDate() {
        return invoiceDate;
    }
    public void setInvoiceDate(Date invoiceDate) {
        this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
    }
    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(long amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public Date getDateReceived() {
        return dateReceived;
    }
    public void setDateReceived(Date dateReceived) {
        this.dateReceived = dateReceived;
    }
    public String getInvoiceNumber() {
        return invoiceNumber;
    }
    public void setInvoiceNumber(String invoiceNumber) {
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }


    public Claim(int provider_claim_id, String policy_number, String provider_code, String membership_number, String member_name, Date transaction_date, Long amount, Date date_received, String smart_invoice_nr, ServiceTag sservicetag){
    this.id = provider_claim_id;
    this.groupCode = policy_number;
    this.providerCode = provider_code;
    this.memberNumber = membership_number;
    this.memberNames = member_name;
    this.invoiceDate = transaction_date;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.dateReceived = date_received;
    this.invoiceNumber = smart_invoice_nr;
    this.serviceTags = sservicetag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("name=%s, organisation=%s", this.memberNames, this.memberNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((memberNames == null) ? 0 : memberNames.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    // Claim objects are equal if they have the same name.
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Claim other = (Claim) obj;
        if (memberNames == null) {
            if (other.memberNames != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!memberNames.equals(other.memberNames))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the other class

```
public class ServiceTag {

    private int transactionId;
    private String serviceDescription;
    private String serviceCode;
    private String serviceAmount;
    private String quantity;  
    private String diagnosis;
    private String serviceType;
    private String serviceCodeType;  
    private String serviceDate;

    public ServiceTag(
             int transactionId,
             String serviceDescription,
             String serviceCode,
             String serviceAmount,
             String quantity,
             String diagnosis,
             String serviceType,
             String serviceCodeType,
             String serviceDate
            ) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.serviceDescription = serviceDescription;
        this.serviceCode = serviceCode;
        this.serviceAmount = serviceAmount;
        this.quantity = quantity;  
        this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
        this.serviceCodeType = serviceCodeType; 
    }


    public int getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }
    public void setTransactionId(int transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }
    public String getServiceDescription() {
        return serviceDescription;
    }
    public void setServiceDescription(String serviceDescription) {
        this.serviceDescription = serviceDescription;
    }
    public String getServiceCode() {
        return serviceCode;
    }
    public void setServiceCode(String serviceCode) {
        this.serviceCode = serviceCode;
    }
    public String getServiceAmount() {
        return serviceAmount;
    }
    public void setServiceAmount(String serviceAmount) {
        this.serviceAmount = serviceAmount;
    }
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public String getDiagnosis() {
        return diagnosis;
    }
    public void setDiagnosis(String diagnosis) {
        this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
    }
    public String getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }
    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }
    public String getServiceCodeType() {
        return serviceCodeType;
    }
    public void setServiceCodeType(String serviceCodeType) {
        this.serviceCodeType = serviceCodeType;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to modify above classes to deserialize this `JSON` properly?

Comment: You have a claims property that is an array. Are you handling that? I this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910753/jackson-deserialization-issues-with-arrays-and-objects.

Comment: You have to create new root POJO which should contains `List<Claim> claims` property.